# Closing jQuery Dialog from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, dialog, reload

I have a page which opens a jQuery dialog on click. The dialog contains an iframed form on a separate page on the same domain. On the parent page, I have the below code:

```
<a class="popup" href="my_form.php">Open Popup</a>

<div id="pop-content" style="display:none;">
    <iframe id="pop-iframe" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".popup").click(function (e) {

            // pass the url from the link to the iframe
            $("#pop-iframe").attr('src', $(this).attr("href"));

            // Open the dialog 
            $("#pop-content").dialog({
                 width: 850,
                 height: 600,
                 show: true,
                 close: function (event, ui) {
                     $(this).dialog('destroy');
                 }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
     });

    // Call this fucntion from the iframe after form submit
    function dialogClose() {          
        $('#pop-content').dialog('close');  // close the iframe      
        window.location.reload();  // reload the parent page
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Once the form is successfully submitted, I need to close the dialog and reload the parent page. To do this, I use PHP to print out the JavaScript below on the page once the form has been submitted:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        window.parent.parent.dialogClose();
    });
</script>
```

The function `dialogClose()`, however, is not being executed. Can someone kindly point me in the right direction?

When using this in `my_form.php` there are no console errors:

```
window.parent.parent.dialogClose()
```

When using this in `my_form.php`:

```
window.parent.dialogClose()
```

the console logs:

> TypeError: window.parent.dialogClose is not a function

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are you including the jquery files in  `my_form.php` ?

Comment: Why don't you call this function at close event of the dialog?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ 

Jquery is included in my_form.php  

When using this on window.parent.parent.dialogClose() my_form.php there are no console errors, however when using window.parent.dialogClose() the console logs:  TypeError: window.parent.dialogClose is not a function

Comment: @Satyaki Chatterjee  This is what I am doing temporarily, however I don't want to reload the parent every time the dialog is closed, only when the form is submitted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be simple..

On the iframed page you only need to look for parent as the dialog itself is part of the parent page

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      parent.dialogClose();
  });
</script>
```

and on the parent page (needed to be on the page, not inside a separate js file for some reason)

```
<script>
  function dialogClose() { 
    window.location.reload(); 
    $("#pop-content").dialog("destroy");      
  };
</script>
```